# ConvertRecord from XML to JSON is giving null values for Decimal Values

Tags: json, xml, apache-nifi

I have a API which receives data in XML to process the xml data and sending it to database am converting it to JSON. all other values are transforming good but the values one with decimal are converting to null, not sure where am doing wrong.
Sample API data in XML

[image]]

After converting the records to JSON using the ConvertRecord Processor am getting this
[image]

We can see the data is been converted to but the decimal values are `null`

The conversion process as follow
[image]

Comment: This could potentially be a bug in NiFi. Feel free to hit us up here: http://nifi.apache.org/mailing_lists.html